# How to test shared libraries with Google Test Framework

Tags: c++, googletest

Originally posted in [googletestframework](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/googletestframework) forum.

I've just started playing with Google C++ Test framework and have worked through the samples.  I'm working with Linux, Eclipse, and the Linux GCC tool chain.  I've also installed the C/C++ Unit Test plugin in Eclipse.

I have a shared library project that I'm trying to write tests for but have hit a problem that I can't figure out.  To test my shared library project, I've built a separate executable project and put my tests in this project.

I've added the necessary include paths and libraries so that everything builds but when I try to run the tests out of my executable project, which links to the classes under test, the test output does not show me anything meaningful.  Here's an example.

This is my test class, a file called ChallengeResponsePacketTest.cpp in the executable project (ChallengeResponsePacket is a class from my shared library project).

```
TEST(ChallengeResponsePacketTest, shouldSerializePacket) {
    const unsigned char SALT[] = {0x01, 0x02, 0x03};
    const char username[] = "daver";
    unsigned char buffer[100];

    ChallengeResponsePacket packet;
    packet.setSaltValue(SALT, sizeof(SALT));
    packet.setCompressionType(0);
    packet.setEncryptionType(0);
    packet.setUsername(username);
    int size = packet.serialize(buffer, sizeof(buffer));

    EXPECT_EQ(12, size);
    EXPECT_EQ(5, buffer[0]);
}
```

And this is the output I'm getting:

```
[----------] 1 test from ChallengeResponsePacketTest
[ RUN      ] ChallengeResponsePacketTest.shouldSerializePacket
gtest_test: ../src/ChallengeResponsePacket.cpp:34: virtual int tnp::ChallengeResponsePacket::serialize(unsigned char*, size_t) const: Assertion `_clientHashLength > 0' failed.
Aborted
```

As you can imagine, the C/C++ Unit Test Plugin has no clue what to do with this.

Is there some reason I'm not getting the usual pretty Google Test Framework output?

I guess another question I have is if this is the best way to use the test framework to test shared library code?

Thanks,

Comment: It looks to me like the library is throwing an exception? The "Assertion `_clientHashLength > 0' failed." part of the line may be the exception message? I don't use Google Test, so I'm not sure what its messages look like when an unexpected exception is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Bret,

That pointed me in the right direction.  Turned out there was something being thrown (or simply failing) in the code.  I can't say for sure what it was because I rewrote the code and the problem went away.  I had a similar problem where the plugin failed with no error but running the test on the command line resulted in a seg fault error message.

I've been doing Java for a long time and have just come back to C++.  I guess I'm used to a more forgiving tools.

Cheers,
Dave.